# Stop Java's JTextField from expanding to fit panel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jtextfield

I'm making an RPG to practice my novice programming abilities. I want to create a bunch of options for character creation in a 1x4 grid, with a confirm button underneath.

My problem here is that I want the JTextField to stop looking like it was designed to consume any and all text the world might possess. See here:

[Okay, well I can't post images yet.]

But it's a giant text field, which I believe is its way of trying to fill the entire panel. I just want to it be roughly the same height as the JLabel next to it.

I've tried setBounds(), setSize(), setPreferredSize()...how can I make that text field appropriately sized?

Edit: Sorry for not posting the relevant code:

```
package practice;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame failFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel failPanel = new JPanel();
        failPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4));

        failPanel.add(new JTextField());
        failPanel.add(new JPanel());
        failPanel.add(new JTextField());
        failPanel.add(new JPanel());

        failFrame.add(failPanel);
        failFrame.setSize(800, 800);
        failFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        failFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This causes the text fields to be far taller than I want them to be. Is it possible to use a gridLayout and make their height lower?

Comment: Post... your... code. Swing uses layout managers to layout components. The way the texfield behaves depend on the layout manager used and how it's used. The setXxxx methods you tried should almost never be used.

Comment: Sorry about that, code is up.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a LayoutManager could help. If the textfield and the label should have the same size you could think about a gridlayout.

see: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: I've been using BorderLayout, and I tried GridLayout just now. That pulled the two items apart, and the JLabel might technically be as gargantuan as the JTextField (I can't tell), but what I should have said is I wanted the JTextField to be as tall as the text in the JLabel. With GridLayout, it's still incredibly tall.

I'm about to try BoxLayout, thanks for that link.

Comment: BoxLayout was no good either. Text field still has an absurdly disproportionate height.

Comment: @MitchellTurlington: don't blindly test all possible layout managers? Learn how they work, and use the appropriate one, with the appropriate settings. The swing tutorial discusses all of them.

Comment: Well, in addition to blindly testing what I had >thought< were all of them (I've been learning from a textbook, being a college student), I've been trying to learn how to use them from the swing tutorials and from googling things like "Java SE 7 BoxLayout."

I've been trying anything I can find that seems like it might work, and sometimes I find something I think SHOULD work, but then doesn't seem to.

I can't figure out the appropriate one or the appropriate settings. Or, I can, but I haven't succeeded yet despite my efforts. I came here for help, since I've been pointed here by Google a lot.

Comment: I'm extremely novice and I'm sorry if you find me ignorant, but the fact is I am ignorant of a great many things dealing with programming. It's not like I haven't been spending hours looking through tutorials and Google while I wait for answers to show up here.